# Changing a crankset on a Specialized sirrus step through

Tags: shimano, crankset, specialized-bikes

I have an issue with pedals to crankset connection on a 1 month old Specialized Sirrus Step Through. Probably connection was done wrongly and they are just falling out of the connection holes. Looks like inside one of these connector holes is totally worn out (no thread left). Also I cannot find only crank levers for this set. So I guess I have 2 options buy the same (which so far I cannot find with short delivery) or make a forced change to something.

Currently installed is Shimano Tourney TY501 (3x8; 48-38-28T, square BB)

I am thinking about Shimano Tourney A070 (3x7/8; 50-39-30T, square BB)

It looks like the closest analogue available, but will it fit without any other changes taking into account the teeth difference (obvious area of concern is front deraullier and chain, both so far I cannot find exact model used for this bike)...

Would appreciate any input or comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A one-month old bike should absolutely be sorted by warranty.  Don't attempt to do anything yourself at this point.  If you can't get to the supplier for C19 reasons, at least make contact by email or phone, so you have a dated record of when you reported the problem.